# How to add html file into active admin page and make it a part of page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

Now I have information in XML format, I need to convert it with stylesheet.xslt to receive HTML table. I try to put this  HTML table into my admin page(I use active admin), but get text of my html file. However I would like to see a table after converting

I tried to put it into different tags(div/pre), don't help

```
pre id: 'response_xml_into_html', class: 'collapse' do
document = Nokogiri::XML(request)
template = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read('stylesheet.xslt'))
template.transform(document)
```

Comment: I believe [`ActionView::Helpers::OutputSafetyHelper#raw`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am not sure, but try this:

```
document = Nokogiri::XML(request)
template = Nokogiri::XSLT(File.read('stylesheet.xslt'))
htmltable_out = template.transform(document)
div(id: 'response_xml_into_html', class: 'collapse') do
  htmltable_out.html_safe
end
```

Also make sure to start a `rails console` en see whether the transformation indeed works. Good luck!